# rails server command WINDOWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, webrick

I am completely new to ror and am following Michael Hartl's tutorial but I keep getting an error when I get to section 1.2.5. using the rails server command. When I use this command (whilst I am in my rail app directory 'first_app') I get the following error

```
c:\Users\rails_projects\first_app>rails server
c:/rails_projects/first_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `groups' for Rails:
Module (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/comma
nds.rb:28:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/comma
nds.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/comma
nds.rb:27:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/comma
nds.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I can't figure out what went wrong, my bundle installed fine (section 1.2.4).

Comment: Show your config/application.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Gemfile` is not set to use rails 3.1 or greater, try updating to 3.1.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I updated the Gemfile then downloaded sqlite3 (putting the dll in the ruby\bin folder) and it works now. Thanks again for answering my question so quickly you were a big help!

Comment: Now I can open it up on my local host but I am getting an error "activerecord connection not established" I tried changing the gem sqlite3 version but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @user1104150 if updating to 3.1 resolved your initial problem, could you mark my answer as correct? That is how we do things on stackoverflow. As to your "activerecord connection not established" issue, that is another problem and you should first try searching this site for a similar question before opening up a new question.